# Doubts on how to write in vector

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, notation

I know I can write a vector like this: $\beta = ( \beta_{1}, \dots, \beta_{p})^{\top}$ and $\rho = (\rho_{1}, \dots, \rho_{q})^{\top}$ by this way it have dimension $p \times 1$ and $q \times 1$, respectively.

Sometimes someone writes this matrix like this: $\mathbf{X}_{(n \times p)} = (\mathbf{x}_{1}^{\top}, \dots, \mathbf{x}_{p}^{\top})^{\top}$ and $\mathbf{W}_{(n \times q)} = (\mathbf{w}_{1}^{\top}, \dots, \mathbf{w}_{q}^{\top})^{\top}$. I´m not sure about this notations.

My question about this is whether I write $\delta = (\beta^{\top}, \rho^{\top})^{\top}$, which is dimension of the $\delta$?  And which is property in that´s possibly to write $\delta$, $\mathbf{X}_{(n \times p)}$ e $\mathbf{W}_{(n \times q)}$ as above.

Comment: Are you sure there is the extra transpose at the end?

Comment: If $\mathbf x_1$ is an $n\times 1$ column vector then $(\mathbf{x}_{1}, \dots, \mathbf{x}_{p})$ (nothing transposed!) is an $n\times p$ matrix. Could you very carefully quote a notation like the one you are interested in and say exactly where you got it (so that someone might be able to check the original source)?

Comment: I would guess that $\delta$ is a 2 by $n$ matrix, where $n$ is the length of $\beta$ and $\rho$. I think the notation $X = (x_1^T,...,x_p^T)^T$ is thinking of $X$ as a column vector of row vectors: so start with some *column* vectors $x_i$ that you want to be the rows of the matrix, then turn them row vectors $x_i^T$, then stack them in a column.

Comment: In my area, it is common to write a (column) vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ as $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$, and therefore $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)^\top$ would represent a row vector. Similarly, if $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m\in\mathbb{R}^n$ are column vectors, I usually see $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m)\in\mathbb{R}^{mn}$ used to represent the concatenation of these vectors into one large column vector, not a matrix. To stack these vectors into a matrix, we usually write $X=\begin{bmatrix}x_1&x_2&\cdots&x_m\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$. The bottom line is this: clearly define your notation before using it.